# Hazelcast Jet - drain the list to a stream

Tags: hazelcast-jet

My Jet job is transforming the Redis stream data - the tranformation is - I lookup a `map` for every item in the stream - if found it contains one or more items (list). I would like to write the items in draining stream as separate items and not as one element of list.

My code works, however it writes the list as a single item to another Redis stream - what I need is write each element of the list separately to the stream (so that the other job can work on items independently).

Code

```java
pipeline.drawFrom(RedisSources.stream("source", uri, "payloads", "$"))
        .withIngestionTimestamps()
        .groupingKey(k -> k.get("eventType"))
        .mapUsingContext(lookupService(), (svc, event, item) -> svc.findHooks(event) /*returns list*/) 
        .drainTo(RedisSinks.stream("drain", uri, "hooks"));
```

So, the returned list from the service should be written as separate elements in the output stream.

What api can I use to emit each item? I couldn't find much in docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map one item into multiple items, you need to use the the [flat map](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/3.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/jet/pipeline/StreamStage.html#flatMapUsingContext-com.hazelcast.jet.pipeline.ContextFactory-com.hazelcast.jet.function.BiFunctionEx-) transform instead of the simple map transform.

Example below:

```java
pipeline.drawFrom(RedisSources.stream("source", uri, "payloads", "$"))
        .withIngestionTimestamps()
        .groupingKey(k -> k.get("eventType"))
        .flatMapUsingContext(lookupService(), (svc, event, item) -> Traversers.traverseIterable(svc.findHooks(event)) /*returns list*/) 
        .drainTo(RedisSinks.stream("drain", uri, "hooks"));
```